# Running Legacy command line application on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit on my pc. I have small command line program (exe) which I used in Windows 7 32 bit, earlier. But when I run it on 64 bit OS, it gives an error message

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer system information to see whether you need x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64 bit) version of the program, and then contact software publisher.

I'm planning to install Windows 7 32 bit as a virtual machine & run this exe on it, is there any other way  To run it on Windows 7 64 bit OS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its probably a 16 bit app - i'd give dosbox a shot, since it would be lighter than running a whole modern windows environment, and 16 bit applications are often dos.

Windows 64 should run 32 bit apps fine, they dropped 16 bit support with 64 bit builds.

Comment: Its almost certainly a 16 bit application then